# Almost surely constant

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $x$ and $y$ be two independent random variables on a probability space $(X,\Sigma,\mathbb{P})$ such that $x+y$ is almost surely constant. Show that both $x$ and $y$ must be almost surely constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, since $\mathbb{R}=\cup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}[n, n+1]$, there must be some $n_0\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(x\in[n_0, n_0+1])>0$. Denote $I_0=[n_0, n_0+1]$. Then we bisect $I_0$ into two closed intervals $S_{01}$ and $S_{02}$, and it must be the case that $\mathbb{P}(x\in S_{01})>0$ or $\mathbb{P}(x\in S_{02})>0$. Without loss of generality, assume that $\mathbb{P}(x\in S_{01})>0$, and let $I_1=S_{01}$. Inductively, suppose that $I_0, I_1, \cdots, I_k$ have all been defined, then we bisect $I_k$ into two closed intervals $S_{k1}$ and $S_{k2}$, and we are sure that $\mathbb{P}(S_{k1})>0$ or $\mathbb{P}(S_{k2})>0$. Denote $I_{k+1}=S_{k1}$ if $\mathbb{P}(S_{k1})>0$, otherwise denote $I_{k+1}=S_{k2}$.

In this way, we will get a nested sequence of closed intervals $\{I_k\}_{k=0}^\infty$. By nested interval theorem, $\cap_{k} I_k=\{a\}$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Since $x$ is not constant almost surely, there must exist some $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(x\in I_m)\in (0,1)$, since otherwise we will have $x=_{a.s.}a$.

Now the contradiction will pop out gradually. As $x+y$ is almost surely constant over $X$, $x+y=_{a.s.}b$ for some $b\in\mathbb{R}$. Hence, $\mathbb{P}(x\in I_m, y\ne b-I_m)\le \mathbb{P}(x+y\ne b)=0$, which, by independence, implies that $\mathbb{P}(x\in I_m)\cdot\mathbb{P}(y\notin b-I_m)=0$. By our construction, $\mathbb{P}(x\in I_m)>0$, and thus $\mathbb{P}(y\notin b-I_m)=0$. On the other hand, since we also have $\mathbb{P}(x\notin I_m)\cdot\mathbb{P}(y\in b-I_m)=\mathbb{P}(x\notin I_m, y\in b-I_m)\le \mathbb{P}(x+y\ne b)=0$, and $\mathbb{P}(x\notin I_m)=1-\mathbb{P}(x\in I_m)>0$ (recall that $\mathbb{P}(x\in I_m)\in (0,1)$), it points to that $\mathbb{P}(y\in b-I_m)=0$, a contradiction! Therefore, $x$ must be constant almost surely, and by the same logic we can argue that $y$ is also constant almost surely over $X$.